# Is it possible to remove a property or at-least set it null from object in a query without changing its type?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-identity, breeze

So i have this LinQ query

```
var users = from user in dbContext.Users
            where user.IsPublic
            select user;
```

The issue is that this user have other properties i don't want returned such as passwordHash or email.

Also selecting into `new User{Id=user.Id, First...}` results into an this classic error.. probably because User extends AspNetIdentityUser

> The entity or complex type 'MyProject.User' cannot be constructed in a
>   LINQ to Entities query.

I know i could create a new class and select into it but i want the returned to be of type `User`

Is it possible to remove a property/field from `User` at-least set it null when making a query without changing its type?

Comment: Look into anonymous types https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: have you tried just  `new {Id=user.Id, First...}` Create anonymous object

Comment: i have tried it just now.... casting it to application user gives me null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all the needed properties to an anonymous type, materialize the result and then use the it to build a list of Users.
First query uses SQL like syntax, second - chain syntax.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<User> Users = new List<User>()
    {
        new User {Id = 1, Name = "N1", IsPublic = true},
        new User {Id = 2, Name = "N2", IsPublic = true},
        new User {Id = 3, Name = "N3"}
    };

    var users1 = from u in (from user in Users
        where user.IsPublic
        select new {user.Id, user.Name}).ToList()
        select new User {Id = u.Id, Name = u.Name};

    var users2 =
        Users.Where(x => x.IsPublic)
            .Select(user => new {user.Id, user.Name})
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => new User {Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name});

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: This works but  gives me IEnumerable<User> as a returned type, All i wanted was IQueryable<User>.. thanks i will stick with this but i really wanted features from IQueryable

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are not allowed to new up entities that are mapped to database in Linq To Entities statement.

This prevents you from selecting partial results into mapped classes. I would advise you to create separate class and return that instead as by using the same class this function signature becomes very misleading - one might expect that it returns full user object.

You can work around this issue by selecting values you need and then creating users outside the query.

Try this:

```
public List<User> GetPublicUsers()
{
    var existingUsers = dbContext.Users
        .Where(u => u.IsPublic);

    var result = new List<User>();
    foreach(var existingUser in existingUsers)
    {
        result.Add(new User { Id = existingUser.Id, ...}));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This gives the error `The entity or complex type 'MyProject.User' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query` i think because i am extending aspIdentityUser

Comment: Oops, thouth it would work. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I just copied your code and got `The body of 'MyProject.Users()' cannot be an iterator block because 'IQueryable<nUser>' is not an iterator interface type`

Comment: Not sure what you are returning, changed code into function that returns list and also aggregated results into that.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
This gives `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProject.User>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyProject.User>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: The solution works perfectly if i change the return type to  List<MyProject.User> but it has to stay IQueryable<MyProject.User> so to allow a user to sort the returning stuff.. using breezejs

Comment: Any attempt to cast returned result to IQueryable<MyProject.User>  results in invalid cast exception or null object... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Well This draws too much from the two answers.. see the return type had to be IQueryable it is not yet complete as i wished to hide some columns completely, i have just manage to modify their values.. i really hate breezejs for making us expose too much of our schema

```
public IQueryable<User> Users()
 {

     var users = from user in _db.Context.Users
         where user.IsPublic
         select user;


     foreach (var user in users)
        {
            user.PasswordHash = null;
            user.PhoneNumber = null;
            user.Logins.Clear();
            user.Email = null;
            user.AccessFailedCount = 0;
            user.Roles.Clear();
            user.SecurityStamp = null;
            user.TwoFactorEnabled = user.EmailConfirmed = user.PhoneNumberConfirmed = false;
            user.Claims.Clear();
        }
        return users;
    }
```

I really wish these columns where invisible to breeze as it just need the Id and Name... but.. i guess this will do.. for now